# Installing Ubuntu 13.04 problem with formatting drive

Tags: installation, 13.04, ssd

I am trying to install 13.04 on a 60 GB SSD, connected via SATA to a LSI 2008 8 port SAS controller on an SuperMicro MBD-H8DG6-F-0 motherboard. The install took an extremely long time (~ an hour) on the `Creating  ext4 file system for /home in partition #1 of LVM VG ubuntu-vg, LV home...` step. If I look in the console, there is a set of messages that repeat:

```
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB:
Write same(16): 93 0B 00 00 00 00 06 0e cf e2 00 00 ff ff 00 00
scsi target4:0:0: handle(0x0009), sas_address(0x44332211000000000), phy(0)
scsi target4:0:0: enclousre_logical_id(0x500304B00be72000), slot(0)
sd 4:0:0:0: task abort: SUCESS scmd(ffffBB3fde47dd00)
```

Finally, it fails to create a mountable /boot, and the install hangs.

I have removed the timestamps, because I am copying this by hand off one monitor and typing it in (similarly there may be errors in the addresses). What could be going wrong? Should I just continue to let this go? I saw some recommendations to upgrade the firmware for my SAS controller on similar messages, but I can't do that without an OS (that I know of).

Comment: what are your hardware specs?

Comment: The most relevant bit is that this is a Kingston ssdNow kc300 60 GB SSD. Mobo is above; dual AMD 6344 twelve-core Opterons; 4 additional Seagate Desktop HDD.15 ST4000DM000 4TB drives

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out. The problem was simple: the firmware that shipped with the motherboard was very out of date, and didn't play nice with the SSD. I followed the instructions here: http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2012-October/129427.html

I'll copy the important part here for anyone who finds this. Note, if you have this motherboard, you can use the 9211_8i (a PCI card) updates. I assume they have the same chipset

9211_8i_Package_P14_IR_IT_Firmware_BIOS_for_MSDOS_Windows\Firmware\HBA_9211_8i_IR\2118ir.bin
and
9211_8i_Package_P14_IR_IT_Firmware_BIOS_for_MSDOS_Windows\sasbios_rel\mptsas2.rom

flashed using
Installer_P14_for_Linux\sas2flash_linux_i686_x86-64_rel\sas2flash

(the linux package3 doesn't include the firmware, so you need to 
download the windows package too).  the IR firmware supports raid while 
the IT firmware is just a jbod HBA.  my cards were already "IR" even 
though I'm not using that feature, so I saw no reason to force the 
restricted firmware on them.

to flash it after you collect the files you need:

```
 # chmod +x sas2flash
 # ./sas2flash -b mptsas2.rom
 .....
 # ./sas2flash -fwall 2118ir.bin
 ....
```